# Coloring plot based on coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing some linear programming for optimization and I need to present the data, using different colors on the surface based on the value of the optimized function. The optimized function requires all three x, y, z coordinates to be passed in, so basically the surface I need to color iw a concave 3D polyhedron. The walls can be vertical as well. My current approach is something like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

verts = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)]

faces = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3]]


ax = a3.Axes3D(plt.figure())
ax.dist = 30
ax.azim = -140
ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax.set_zlim([0, 1])
for face in faces:
    triangle = verts[face[0]], verts[face[1]], verts[face[2]]
    face = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([triangle])
    face.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3)))
    ax.add_collection3d(face)

plt.show()
```

But this allows me only to set a single color to a face. My concept is doing it by simply increasing the number of polygons on each wall, but isn't there a simpler way like passing a 3d function to the plot which would map a color to a point based on all three coordinates (I've seen examples for colormaps taking only x and y arguments, but it does not handle vertical walls accordingly.

Comment: Unfortnately I do not understand the problem and the desired outcome. Can you please describe **precisely** what you are expecting your final plot to look like?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think he wants something like `contourf` but per face of his polygon.

Comment: Can you show us an example where you 'increase the number of polygons on each wall' so that we can get an idea what the colouring scheme should be?

Comment: The coloring scheme is supposed to be provided by a function taking the coordinates of the point. and returning a color value. The increasing is still not done, but it is the only option I see right now - dividing one wall into smaller ones and coloring them separately (like pixel by pixel, but here it would be polygon by polygon) based on the center of it.